# Reply to email V3 email (v3) is not working

Tags: azure, office365, azure-logic-apps

I'm getting this error

```
 "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "source": "logic-apis-centralus.azure-apim.net",
    "clientRequestId": "392138e8-1e84-42b0-997c-f08297a077c4",
    "message": "The response is not in a JSON format.",
}
```

I'm also sending the message Id from http request and it was successfully parsed from request and set as a parameter in reply to email v3

[image]

It is able to get messageId from the request and then it tries to send reply to that particular email and it gives this error

[image]

Comment: We cannot possibly help you in any meaningful way without seeing your code as a [mre]. Please review [ask]

Comment: Show your flow and we can help.